# how to repeat rows only once in many to many relationship

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, mysqli

I'm working on many to many relationship on php 
I have 3 tables , movie table which contains movie name and movie id
genre table which contains genre and genre id
and movie_genre table which has movie id and genre id 

 genre table has these values

```
(1 ,'action'),
(2 ,'comedy'),
(3 ,'drama'),
(4 ,'mystery');
```

I used the code below to fetch the data

```
 $query = " SELECT movie_name,movie_id,genre FROM movies
    JOIN movie_genre ON movies.movie_id = movie_genre.movie_id
    JOIN genre ON movie_genre.genre_id = genre.genre_id
    WHERE movie.movie_id = ?";


    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query);
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    echo ' movie_id: '.$row["movie_id"].' movie name:'.$row["movie_name"].'
    Genres:' .$row["genre"]

        }}
```

but the result would be like
movie_id movie_name genre[1]
movie_id movie_name genre[2]
movie_id movie_name genre[3]
an example

```
movie_id:55 movie name: titanic genre : action 

movie_id:55 movie name: titanic genre : drama

movie_id:55 movie name: titanic genre : romance
```

the result I want is

```
movie_id:55 movie name: titanic genre : action drama romance
```

I did try using limit 1 but the result was showing only the first genre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Will need to do a loop just for the genres** I can't test this, so this is throwing together just what I imagine will work, but it will be something along these lines, there might be errors in syntax here

```
$query = " SELECT movie_name,movie_id,genre FROM movies
    JOIN movie_genre ON movies.movie_id = movie_genre.movie_id
    JOIN genre ON movie_genre.genre_id = genre.genre_id
    WHERE movie.movie_id = ?";    

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query);
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ){

    // if it's greater than zero, great, we have at least 1 movie.
    // but if it's greater than 1, then we know we have more than 1 genre

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo 'movie_id:'.$row["movie_id"].'movie name:'.$row["movie_name"];
    break; // so it only runs through this loop once, instead of using limit
    }//end while

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 1 ){
    // more than 1 genre so loop and print out just genres
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {    
      echo $row["genre"];    
    }//end while
    }//end if more than 1 genre
    }//end if
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT movie_name,movie_id, GROUP_CONCAT(genre SEPARATOR ' ') AS genre
FROM movies
JOIN movie_genre ON movies.movie_id = movie_genre.movie_id
JOIN genre ON movie_genre.genre_id = genre.genre_id
WHERE movie.movie_id = ?
GROUP BY movie_name,movie_id
```